# Segment(aka Struct Segment) has no member named v (or w)

Tags: c

I am getting this error on the last printf line, however the v  & w members have already been declared before, it normally should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct Point {
float x;
float y;
float z;
};
typedef struct Point Point;

    struct Segment{
    Point a;
    Point b;
    };
    typedef struct Segment Segment;


int main(){
Point v = {4.1,6.2,9.3}, w= {3.3,6.6,9.9};
    Segment s;
    s.a = v;
    s.b = w;
printf("(%.1f, %.1f , %.1f) --- (%.1f , %.1f , %.1f)", s.v.x, s.v.y, s.v.z, s.w.x, s.w.y, s.w.z);
return 0;
}
```

It's been hurting my head for about 45 minutes now ._.

Comment: `w` and `v` are not defined as *members* of anything; they are variables located in `main`.

Comment: The error message is fairly self-explanatory, so you’d need to explain a bit morer.

Comment: Even though I answered your question, please format your code for readability.

Comment: @blamayl9anichi7edbrojol What is unclear with the error message?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The type Segment has two members `a` and `b` and you would print them like this:

```
printf("(%.1f, %.1f , %.1f) --- (%.1f , %.1f , %.1f)",
   s.a.x, s.a.y, s.a.z,
   s.b.x, s.b.y, s.b.z);
```

This is how you would print the variables `v` and `w`:

```
printf("(%.1f, %.1f , %.1f) --- (%.1f , %.1f , %.1f)",
   v.x, v.y, v.z,
   w.x, w.y, w.z);
```